# Cartesian Product of Two SharePoint Lists

Tags: custom-list

I have the following two SharePoint Lists. I want to get the Cartesian Product of these two lists, append "-" between the items and store in another list. Please let me know how do I do this? 
("00.0","01.0","02.0","03.0","04.0","04.1","04.2","04.3","04.4","04.5","05.0","05.1","05.2","06.0","07.0","08.0","09.0","10.0","10.1","10.2","10.3","10.4","10.5","11.0","11.1","11.2","11.3","11.4","12.0","12.1","12.2","13.0","14.0","15.0","16.0","17.0","18.0","18.1","19.0","20.0","21.0","21.1","21.2","21.3","22.0","23.1","23.2","23.3","23.4","23.5","24.0","24.1","24.2","25.0","25.1","25.2","26.1","26.2","26.3","26.4","26.5","27.1","27.2","27.3","27.4","28.1","28.2","29.1","29.2","30.1","30.2","30.3","30.4","30.5","31.0")

("PL","PR","FO","CE","OC","JD","TD","LD")

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PowerShell solution:

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://c4968397007
$l1 = $w.Lists['List1']
$l2 = $w.Lists['List2']
$l3 = $w.Lists['List3']
$i1 = $l1.Items
$i2 = $l2.Items
$i1 | % {$item1=$_;($i2 | % {$item3 = $l3.Items.Add();$item3['Title']="$($item1.Title)-$($_.Title)";$item3.Update()})}
```

Comment: I have to write the code in C# instead of Powershell